# Add microdata stock availbility Magento 2

Tags: magento2, stock

I have a default file, where rendering price and adding some microdata, I need to add **stock availbility**, but I can't find a right way.

```
/app/design/frontend/Theme/myTheme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/price/amount/default.phtml
```

```
<?php /** @var \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render\Amount $block */ ?>

<span class="price-container <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getAdjustmentCssClasses() ?>">
    <?php if ($block->getDisplayLabel()): ?>
        <span class="price-label"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getDisplayLabel(); ?></span>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <span <?php if ($block->getPriceId()): ?> id="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getPriceId() ?>"<?php endif;?>
        <?php echo($block->getPriceDisplayLabel()) ? 'data-label="' . $block->getPriceDisplayLabel() . $block->getPriceDisplayInclExclTaxes() . '"' : '' ?>
        data-price-amount="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getDisplayValue(); ?>"
        data-price-type="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getPriceType(); ?>"
        class="price-wrapper <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getPriceWrapperCss(); ?>"
        <?php echo $block->getSchema() ? ' itemprop="price"' : '' ?>>
        <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->formatCurrency($block->getDisplayValue(), (bool)$block->getIncludeContainer()) ?>
    </span>
    <?php if ($block->hasAdjustmentsHtml()): ?>
        <?php echo $block->getAdjustmentsHtml() ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php if ($block->getSchema()): ?>
        <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getDisplayCurrencyCode()?>" />
    <?php endif; ?>
</span>
```

If I add this part:

```
<?php if ($block->displayProductStockStatus()): ?>
    <?php if ($_product->isAvailable()): ?>
          <link itemprop="availability" href="http://schema.org/InStock">
    <?php else: ?>
          <link itemprop="availability" href="http://schema.org/OutOfStock">
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I get error Invalid Method: displayProductStockStatus()

Please provide me, how can I do it right. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same problem and I used the following solution with Magneto 2.3.2 in my custom theme based on the Magento blank theme:

First, I removed the schema.org markup from

```
/app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/price/amount/default.phtml
```

I added the block with schema.org/Offer markup to:

```
/app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Catalog/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/attributes.phtml
```

My final code for the schema.org/offers markup looks like:

```
<div itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
  <meta itemprop="price" content="<?php echo $_product->getFinalPrice(); ?>" />
  <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="<?php $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
  $currencysymbol = $objectManager->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
  echo $currency = $currencysymbol->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode(); ?>" />
  <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="<?php echo $_product->getCurrencyCode() ?>" />
  <meta itemprop="url" content="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl(); ?>">
  <?php if ($_product->isAvailable()): ?>
      <link itemprop="availability" href="http://schema.org/InStock">
  <?php else: ?>
      <link itemprop="availability" href="http://schema.org/OutOfStock">
  <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Depending on the product type you sell, you may have to extend the existing markup with custom product attributes. Here in this file I can add all other custom markups.
To include these additional attributes, I use the following code (replace `custom_attribute` with the attribute you wish to include here):

```
<meta itemprop="custom_attribute" content="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('custom_attribute')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product); ?>" />
```

Example for SKU:

```
<meta itemprop="sku" content="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('sku')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product); ?>" />
```

You can check your final code with with the structured data testing tool from Google: https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool

Comment: thats by far the best and cleanest sollution!

Answer (score 1):

You're editing the wrong file,
Do it in the default.phtml file
https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/b1e56ed3b6f13f1ab780d8eddc33fc04cb6ecf75/app/code/Magento/Catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/type/default.phtml
First copy it to your theme, then edit it.

Answer (score 1):

Just been doing this for an m2.4 site that I manage. Found out that you can do

```
    <?php $_product = $block->getSaleableItem() ?>
    <?php if ($_product): ?>
        <link itemprop="availability" href="<?= ($_product->isAvailable()) ? "https://schema.org/InStock" : "https://schema.org/OutOfStock"; ?>" />
    <?php endif; ?>
```

In /view/base/templates/product/price/amount/default.phtml (Obviously coping into theme).